# What is lkujhbkj0?

Tags: wordpress

I activated BuddyPress on Wordpress 3.9 and on BuddyPress pages (as register) it appears this strange code.

Googling it, it appears that many BuddyPress sites show the same code.

What is it? Is there a way to hide it?

Thanks

EDIT: 
The Wordpress installation is indeed with a commercial theme named Avada.
The behaviour can be seen in a page like [this](https://www.scorbit.org/members/abbycase/) one, which is the profile page of a BuddyPress profile. 
I would be able to post a solution for the question, but apparently I cannot...

[SOLUTION](http://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/remove-sidebar-from-buddypress-member-directory)
I found this on line 39 in the buddypress.php file in the Avada theme folder

```
<?php echo "lkujhbkj".$post->ID; ?>
```

This solved my issue

```
<span style="display:none"><?php echo "lkujhbkj".$post->ID; ?></span>
```

Comment: Whatever it is, it's hilarious.

Comment: Can't find it in the BuddyPress site under blog/faq/search/support. Not in wordpress itself (latest version synced to github in any case).

Comment: I was editing the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 45 results when googling for this string. What all sites with this bug have in common is the theme ***Avada***:

> [image: one site]

. . .

> [image: another site]

As confirmed by the OP, the theme has the following code:

```
<?php echo "lkujhbkj".$post->ID; ?>
```

It makes no sense at all (in WP, HTML, JS or CSS terms) and, I think, can be safely removed.

Comment: I don't know why, but today there are 1.600 results on my google :? Anyways, this Question is nº 1 :)